# Jquery ajax call to asmx web service with soapui like behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP UI call that is working but I want to use Jquery to do it, is this possible?

**SOAPUI request**

`http://rpmdev.company.com/WebServices/wsUserMaint.asmx`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rpm="http://www.company.com/rpm">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <rpm:UserMaintanaceHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rpm:Username>dsd</rpm:Username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rpm:Password>asdf</rpm:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rpm:GeoCode>?</rpm:GeoCode>
      </rpm:UserMaintanaceHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rpm:ResetPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rpm:Hdr>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rpm:Username>RPMUser</rpm:Username>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rpm:Password>cpass</rpm:Password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rpm:GeoCode>ABC</rpm:GeoCode>
         </rpm:Hdr>
         <!--Optional:-->

          <rpm:UserID>JMILLER</rpm:UserID>
      </rpm:ResetPassword>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then I get a response back from server that looks like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ResetPasswordResponse xmlns="http://www.company.com/rpm">
         <ResetPasswordResult>true</ResetPasswordResult>
      </ResetPasswordResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**The Web Service**

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Reset a users password"), SoapHeader("Header", Direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.In)> _
Public Function ResetPassword(ByVal Hdr As UserMaintanaceHeader, ByVal UserID As String) As Boolean
    Dim blResetPassword As Boolean = False

    Try
        Header.Username = Hdr.Username
        Header.Password = Hdr.Password
        Header.GeoCode = Hdr.GeoCode
        Login()

        'resetting the password
        'Check the SiteID, If empty then default it to -1
        Dim SiteID As Integer = -1
        _RPMUser = RPMUser.GetUser(UserID, SiteID)
        _RPMUser.PasswordReset(_ServerName, _ProtocolName)
        _RPMUser = CType(_RPMUser.Save(), RPMUser)
        blResetPassword = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        HandleWebMethodException(ex)
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return blResetPassword
End Function
```

(most of the time the code is c# , that code happens to be vb.net , but it should be clear on what it is doing   , passing in a complex object  HEADER , and userID )

So what I WANT to do is to have jQuery AJAX call in my asp.net mvc html razor page to call up the web method (web service)  and then return back the response to me?

1. It is even possible
2. Do I need to contruct XML as a string?
3. Should I be using `data: "..."` ?
4. Do I need jsonp?
5. Any examples out there on how to do this?

Here is what I was starting with:

```
<script>



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: "http://rpmdev.company.com/WebServices/wsUserMaint.asmx?op=ResetPassword",
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://rpmdev.company.com',
        },
        data: "{}",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = msg.d;
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: have you tried [this](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap)?

Comment: Looking to roll my own without a 3rd party